# How to find $x$ satisfying $-\frac{1}{2}\pi \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}\pi$ such that $\sin x = \sin\left(\frac{97}{17}\pi\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, fractions

I have a few set of these questions which I'm kind of confused about how to answer. I don't particularly need an answer just an explanation of how it's done.

Provide answers in the form $\frac pq \pi$, with $\frac pq$ a fraction in the lowest possible terms.

Find $x$, $-\frac 12 \pi \le x \le \frac 12 \pi$, such as that $\sin x = \sin\left(\frac {97}{17} \pi\right)$.

I don't quite understand what is meant by the less than $x$, this question is maybe really simple as it's early on in my worksheet but I just have no idea on how to address it.
Thanks

edit: grammar

Comment: what do you mean $$\sin\left(\frac{97}{17}\pi\right)$$?

Comment: Are you missing an equals sign, is it $\sin x = \sin \frac{97}{17} \pi$? In either case, your job is to give an angle between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, something on the right half of the unit circle.

Comment: Whoops, lemme edit the question to add it in

Comment: You may find this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the diagram below:

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

Two angles have the same sine if the $y$-coordinates of the points where they intersect the unit circle are equal.  Hence, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if 
$\varphi = \theta$ or $\varphi = \pi - \theta$.  Any angle coterminal with these angles will also have the same sine.  In general, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if 
$$\varphi = \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi - \theta + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$

You wish to solve the equation 
$$\sin x = \sin\left(\frac{97}{17}\pi\right)$$
in the interval $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.  The general solution to the equation is 
$$x = \frac{97}{17}\pi + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
\begin{align*}
x & = \pi - \frac{97}{17}\pi + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}\\ 
  & = -\frac{80}{17}\pi + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
Observe that if we set $k = -3$, we obtain
$$x = \frac{97}{17}\pi - 6\pi = -\frac{5}{17}\pi$$
and that 
$$-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq -\frac{5}{17}\pi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Since the angles satisfying the equation 
$$x = \frac{97}{17}\pi + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
differ by integer multiples of $2\pi$, any other value of $k$ will yield an angle outside the desired interval.

Observe that if $m = 2$, then 
$$x = -\frac{80}{17}\pi + 4\pi = -\frac{12}{17}\pi < -\frac{\pi}{2}$$
and that if $m = 3$, then
$$x = -\frac{80}{17}\pi + 6\pi = \frac{22}{17}\pi > \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Since the angles satisfying the equation 
$$x = -\frac{80}{17}\pi + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$ 
differ by integer multiples of $2\pi$, any other value of $m$ will also yield an angle outside the desired interval.

Hence, the only valid solution of the equation $\sin x = \sin\left(\frac{97}{17}\pi\right)$ satisfying the inequalities $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ is $x = -\frac{5\pi}{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x=\sin \frac{97\pi}{17}$

**If we need to find $x$ then it should be between $-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}$**

$\frac{97\pi}{17}=\frac{17\cdot 5\pi + 12\pi}{17}=5\pi + \frac{12\pi}{17}=5\pi +\pi - \frac{5\pi}{17} $

$\sin x=\sin \frac{5\pi}{17}$

$∴x=\frac{5\pi}{17} $

$∵\frac{5\pi}{17}∈\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right ]$

Comment: If you have any doubt then ask in comments.

Comment: You probably meant $85\pi$ in the first step and not $17.5\pi$

Comment: Hi, I'm having a read of this again, can you explain why 17 x 5 + 12 is used in the beginning?

Comment: @IceArt because we know $\sin ( n\pi + (-1)^n(\theta ) = \sin (\theta)$ , I wrote it as multiple of $17$ because denominator is $17$ and we get integral multiple of $\pi$ and hence we can reduce angle to get in range of $\left [ - \dfrac{\pi}{2} , \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right ]$